# ¿Como puedo incluir un buscador ajax mi código?

Tags: php, ajax, buscador

```
<div class="container ">
        <div class="w3-container ">     
            <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevoUsu">Nuevo</a><br><br>
                        <div class="table table-striped">
              <table class="table table-hover" style="border-color: #337ab7;">
                <tr style="color: #fff; background-color: #960101; border-color: #337ab7;">
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>AGENCIA</th>
                    <th>DEPARTAMENTO</th>
                    <th>AREA</th>
                    <th>NOMBRE</th>
                    <th>EXTENSION</th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></th>
                </tr>   

                </div>      


<?php  
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lista");     
            mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                echo  "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                exit();
            }
            $consulta= "SELECT * FROM lista";
            if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) 
            {
                while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) 
                {               
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$fila[0]</td><td>$fila[1]</td><td>$fila[2]</td><td>$fila[3]</td><td>$fila[4]</td><td>$fila[5]</td>";  
                    echo"<td>";                     
                    echo"<a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editUsu' data-id='" .$fila[0] ."' data-agencia='" .$fila[1] ."' data-departamento='" .$fila[2] ."' data-area='" .$fila[3] ."' data-nombre='" .$fila[4] ."'data-extencion='" .$fila[5] ."'class='btn btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>Editar</a> ";            

                    echo "<a class='btn btn-danger' href='elimina.php?id=" .$fila[0] ."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>Eliminar</a>";     
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                $resultado->close();
            }
            $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: ¿De que forma quieres buscar, por columna o por coincidencias en toda la tabla?¿Con un `input`, `select`, `checbox`, etc?, tienes que agregar un poco mas de información para que quede mas claro lo que deseas

Comment: Buscar en toda la tabla por nombre o departamento

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr esto necesitas tener 2 `<input type="radio" name="" value="">` y 1 `<input type="text" name="">` con los radio button son las opciones de busqueda.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("keyup","#buscador",function(){
  buscar($(this),"tabla")//se llama a la funcion de busqueda y le pasamos el input y el nombre de la tabla.
 })
})
function buscar(input,tabla){
 var columna=$(".filtro:checked").val()//obtenemos el valor de la columna a buscar ejem:0=id; 1=AGENCIA; 4=NOMBRE; numero es la posicion de la columna;
 if(input.val()!=""){
  search=input.val().toLowerCase()
  $("#"+tabla+" tbody tr").hide()
  $("#"+tabla+" tbody tr").find("td:eq("+columna+")").each(function(){//Con td:eq buscamos por el indice de la columna en la tabla valor obtenido en var columna=$(".filtro:checked").val() 
   match=$(this).html().toLowerCase()
   if(match.indexOf(search)!=-1){
    $(this).parent("tr").show();    
   }
  })
 }else{
  $("#"+tabla+" tbody tr").show();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla" class="table table-hover" style="border-color: #337ab7;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th><input class="filtro" type="radio" name="filtro" value="2" checked><label>Departamento</label></th>
   <th><input class="filtro" type="radio" name="filtro" value="4"><label>Nombre</label></th>
   <th colspan="5"><input id="buscador" type="text" name="buscador" placeholder="Buscar"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #fff; background-color: #960101; border-color: #337ab7;">
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>AGENCIA</th>
   <th>DEPARTAMENTO</th>
   <th>AREA</th>
   <th>NOMBRE</th>
   <th>EXTENSION</th>
   <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Agencia 1</td>
   <td>Administracion</td>
   <td>Area 1</td>
   <td>Arturo</td>
   <td>Extencion 1</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Agencia 2</td>
   <td>RRHH</td>
   <td>Area 2</td>
   <td>Marcos</td>
   <td>Extencion 2</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Agencia 3</td>
   <td>Desarrollador</td>
   <td>Area 3</td>
   <td>Mauricio</td>
   <td>Extencion 3</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>

</table>
```

espero que te sirva